# Installation of 14.04 on Asus Zenbook UX301LA alongside Windows

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, laptop, asus

I am afraid I messed up things pretty badly while trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 or Mint 17 on a brand new Asus Zenbook UX301LA. The situation is:

- I am pretty sure that I have destroyed Windows8 (that's fine)
- I think I have installed Linux somehow
- I can't boot for some reasons I do not understand, and Boot Repair did not solve the problem either.

Details are here: http://paste2.org/vLk6tdxN. 
I tried many BIOS configurations. At the moment:

- secure boot is disabled
- CSM is enabled
- not sure of what to do with Sata settings of the 2 SSD (256GB each): should I leave RAID on, at least during installation, or may I choose AHCI?

The important thing is that I do **not** need the preserve partitions/data. Rather, I don't need Windows and **I am willing to erase everything** (provided there are no problems in doing that, with this Asus) and just install Linux on a good old /dev/sda, instead of all this mess of partitions and containers which I don't understand (see http://paste2.org/vLk6tdxN for my boot-repair log).

This is the first new PC I've had with EFI, Win8 and this sort of stuff.

At the moment, the pc boots only with a live distro.

Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX301LA
Ubuntu: 14.04

Comment: Have you found any solution to your problem? Please, provide it to us as your own answer if you have anything. It is good to answer own questions.

Answer (score -1):

Check out my blog post here : http://ux51vz.blogspot.ca

Might be a bit late, I guess you might figured it out already, but anyway, might help you as well... Instructions are for UX51VZ but I am pretty sure it can apply to UX301LA as well as the specs are pretty similar.

I you wanted to keep Win8, you can still restore it from the backup partition an reinstall Linux after.

Comment: You linked your blog home address. Whitch post are you talking about ? Moreover whilst this link may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Please, note that we do not like link-only answers. Please, provide us your answer here.